# I got this error how i can fix: it An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1

Tags: c#

> `using PhotonPackageParser;
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
>
> namespace Albion.Network
> {
> internal sealed class AlbionParser : PhotonParser, IPhotonReceiver
> {
> private readonly HandlersCollection handlers;
>
> public AlbionParser()
> {
> handlers = new HandlersCollection();
> }
>
> public void AddHandler(PacketHandler handler)
> {
> handlers.Add(handler);
> }
>
> protected override void OnEvent(byte Code, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
> {
> if (Code == 3)
> {
> Parameters.Add(1, EventCodes.Move);
> }
>
> short eventCode = ParseEventCode(Parameters);
> if (eventCode == 27)
> {
> Console.Write("EventCode: " + eventCode + " [");
> Parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x.Key + " {" + x.Value + "::" + ObjectDumper.Dump(x.Value, 2) + "},"));
> Console.WriteLine("]");
> }
>
> var eventPacket = new EventPacket(eventCode, Parameters);
>
> handlers.HandleAsync(eventPacket);
> }
>
> protected override void OnRequest(byte OperationCode, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
> {
> short operationCode = ParseOperationCode(Parameters);
> var requestPacket = new RequestPacket(operationCode, Parameters);
>
> handlers.HandleAsync(requestPacket);
> }
>
> protected override void OnResponse(byte OperationCode, short ReturnCode, string DebugMessage, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
> {
> short operationCode = ParseOperationCode(Parameters);
> var responsePacket = new ResponsePacket(operationCode, Parameters);
>
> handlers.HandleAsync(responsePacket);
> }
>
> private short ParseOperationCode(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
> {
> if (!parameters.TryGetValue(253, out object value))
> {
> throw new InvalidOperationException();
> }
>
> return (short)value;
> }
>
> private short ParseEventCode(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
> {
> if (!parameters.TryGetValue(252, out object value))
> {
> throw new InvalidOperationException();
> }
>
> return (short)value;
> }
> }
> }     `

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
using PhotonPackageParser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Albion.Network {
internal sealed class AlbionParser : PhotonParser, IPhotonReceiver
{
    private readonly HandlersCollection handlers;

    public AlbionParser()
    {
        handlers = new HandlersCollection();
    }

    public void AddHandler<TPacket>(PacketHandler<TPacket> handler)
     {
         handlers.Add(handler);
     }

     protected override void OnEvent(byte Code, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
     {
         if (Code == 3)
         {
             Parameters.Add(252, EventCodes.Move);
         }

         short eventCode = ParseEventCode(Parameters);
         if (eventCode == 27)
        {
             Console.Write("EventCode: " + eventCode + " [");
             Parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x.Key + " {" + x.Value + "::" + ObjectDumper.Dump(x.Value, 2) + "},"));
             Console.WriteLine("]");
         }

         var eventPacket = new EventPacket(eventCode, Parameters);

         _ = handlers.HandleAsync(eventPacket);
     }

     protected override void OnRequest(byte OperationCode, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
     {
         short operationCode = ParseOperationCode(Parameters);
         var requestPacket = new RequestPacket(operationCode, Parameters);

         _ = handlers.HandleAsync(requestPacket);
     }

     protected override void OnResponse(byte OperationCode, short ReturnCode, string DebugMessage, Dictionary<byte, object> Parameters)
     {
         short operationCode = ParseOperationCode(Parameters);
         var responsePacket = new ResponsePacket(operationCode, Parameters);

         _ = handlers.HandleAsync(responsePacket);
     }

     private short ParseOperationCode(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
     {
         if (!parameters.TryGetValue(253, out object value))
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException();
         }

         return (short)value;
     }

     private short ParseEventCode(Dictionary<byte, object> parameters)
     {
         if (!parameters.TryGetValue(252, out object value))
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException();
         }

         return (short)value;
     }
 } 
}
```

Thanks for negative btw